# TypeError: undefined is not a function when accessing Date methods

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var d = "12/12/2012"
var t = "13:04"
var m = Date.parse(d+' '+t) //returns **1355299440000**
m.getFullYear() // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I don't know what's wrong I am doing now as it was working earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your variable `m` to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

*Use*

```
var m = new Date(Date.parse(d+' '+t));
```

```js
var d = "12/12/2012";
var t = "13:04";
var m = new Date(Date.parse(d+' '+t)); //returns **1355299440000**
alert(m.getFullYear())
```